# Block users from seeing a List Form?

Tags: 2010, permissions, content-editor-web-part, script-webpart, forms-7

I have a list, and have created multiple edit forms.

Is there a way that I can create a page view that is limited to only certain users, and when they click edit, only their version of the form appears?

Basically how can I override the edit icon to set it to the "new" edit page?

AND

How can I limit who can see a page?

I DO NOT have INFOPATH OR ANY OTHER WEBDEVELOPER SOFTWARE, so this must be done using web parts.

Tammy

Answer (score 0):

You can put a JavaScript to bounce the user to the correct view in list view web part on each view page.

For example, look here:

[Custom list view by using the "JS Link" property](https://msftplayground.com/2014/08/custom-list-view-by-using-the-js-link-property/)